# Tree categories from products collection

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, category-tree

**If I have a collection like this:**

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
   ->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToFilter('my_custom_attribbute','my custom value');
```

What is the **best method** to extract the category tree from this collection? **(Maybe changing the collection with some joins)**

```
- Category 1
  -- Sub 1
  -- Sub 2
- Category 2
  ...
```